# Default method for form post javascript Best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to post a form using JavaScript. The issue is that when I hit the Login button Get method is called *from Mobile* instead of post method.

I am using form post with JavaScript validation. Incase of *Mobile* the HTML form post method is getting called.

The ajax code I am using for form submit is

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            //data: return data from server
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //if fails      
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code with the mobile detection and the html. Or could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Jerodev Sir I can try adding the jsfiddle. It will take some time as I have not tried this before. If you can help me with this let me know. Thank you. :(

Comment: It's not verry hard, you go to http://jsfiddle.net/, you put your html code in the html field, and instead of putting the javascript between the script tags, you put it in the javascript field. when you click run, the result will be visible in the result field. Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: @Jerodev I will try to put it up. Thank you so much for being Humble :)

Comment: @JoeFrambach Both are not the cases. <form> tag have the post method also there is not <a> anchor included inside the form. I am just adding return; on the submit button is that not sufficient?

Comment: I think you should bind this function to the form submit event, and not to the button click event.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I am using the function for submit $('button[type="submit"]').click (function (event) {event.preventDefault();}); and inside this function I am calling the above written code.

Comment: @JoeFrambach May be thats the trick. I will try that and revert. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @JoeFrambach actually I am putting up some check for bot logins. So could not submit the form directly. This is the reason I am using the Button for submitting the form. Could you help me with some other option. This one is not working. :(

Comment: The question can not be answered with the information provided. You need to edit your question with more context.